# Java, Jackson, Custom deserializer with extended classes

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

Using Jackson 2.10., I am trying to write a custom deserializer for a base class, but I have to deserialize fields with unknown field name. Then there are extended class that can also extend this serializer.

I have tried to use the @AnyGetter, and @AnySetter to accomplish it, and it kind of does work. Now I am just wondering if there is a way to do it through a custom deserializer.

I could do it with a base class, but it fails when some class extends it.

Here is the sample of what I have done.
The following is just the base class and its serializer and how I used in in the main.

```java
//BaseClass
@JsonDeserialize(using = BaseClassDeserializer.class)
public static class BaseClass {
  private ObjectNode customFields = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
  private int baseInt;

  public int getBaseInt() {
    return baseInt;
  }

  public void setBaseInt(int baseInt) {
    this.baseInt = baseInt;
  }

  public JsonNode getCustomFields() {
    return customFields;
  }

  public void setCustomFields(ObjectNode customFields) {
    this.customFields = customFields;
  }

  public void putCustomFields(String key, JsonNode node) {
    this.customFields.set(key, node);
  }
}
```

```java
// BaseClassDeserializer
public static class BaseClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<BaseClass> {
  public BaseClassDeserializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public BaseClassDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
  }

  @Override
  public BaseClass deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    BaseClass result = new BaseClass();
    JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    result.setBaseInt((Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("baseInt")).numberValue());
    node.fieldNames();
    Iterator<String> iterator = node.fieldNames();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      String fieldName = iterator.next();
      if (!"baseInt".equals(fieldName)) {
        result.putCustomFields(fieldName, node.get(fieldName));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

```java
// main
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
  String json = "{\n"
      + "\t\"baseInt\": 1,\n"
      + "\t\"customObject\" : {\n"
      + "\t\t\"key\": \"value\"\n"
      + "\t},\n"
      + "\t\"customString\" : \"STRING\",\n"
      + "\t\"extendedString\" : \"STRING\"\n"
      + "}";

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  BaseClass myClass = mapper.readValue(json, BaseClass.class);

}
```

By going looking through the debugger, the fields are successfully loaded.

Now I am trying to extend `BaseClass`

```
// ExtendedClass
public static class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
  @JsonProperty("extendedString")
  private String extendedString;

  public String getExtendedString() {
    return extendedString;
  }

  public void setExtendedString(String extendedString) {
    this.extendedString = extendedString;
  }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
  String json = "{\n"
      + "\t\"baseInt\": 1,\n"
      + "\t\"customObject\" : {\n"
      + "\t\t\"key\": \"value\"\n"
      + "\t},\n"
      + "\t\"customString\" : \"STRING\",\n"
      + "\t\"extendedString\" : \"STRING\"\n"
      + "}";

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  ExtendedClass myClass = mapper.readValue(json, ExtendedClass.class);

}
```

And this crashes with a 
`BaseClass cannot be cast to ExtendedClass` exception.

I am guessing I have to pass along the deserialization to the child class' deserializer, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

In your deserialiser you always return object of type `BaseClass` and it can not be cast to `ExtendedClass`. You need to implement type recognition feature in your deserialiser. In your case, returned type depends from properties `JSON` payload contains. If `JSON` payload contains `extendedString` property you know you need to return `ExtendedClass` in other case just return `BaseClass`. Your deserialiser could look like below:

```
class BaseClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<BaseClass> {

    public BaseClassDeserializer() {
        super(BaseClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public BaseClass deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode root = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

        List<String> names = getNames(root);
        BaseClass result = findAndInitCustomType(names, root);
        result = initBase(names, result, root);
        initCustomFields(names, root, result);

        return result;
    }

    private void initCustomFields(List<String> names, ObjectNode root, BaseClass result) {
        for (String name : names) {
            result.putCustomFields(name, root.get(name));
        }
    }

    private BaseClass findAndInitCustomType(List<String> names, ObjectNode root) {
        final String extendedString = "extendedString";
        if (names.contains(extendedString)) {
            ExtendedClass result = new ExtendedClass();
            result.setExtendedString(root.get(extendedString).asText());
            names.remove(extendedString);
            return result;
        }
        // else - check other custom fields for another types.
        // if not available return null
        return null;
    }

    private BaseClass initBase(List<String> names, BaseClass baseClass, ObjectNode root) {
        if (baseClass == null) {
            baseClass = new BaseClass();
        }
        final String baseInt = "baseInt";
        if (names.contains(baseInt)) {
            baseClass.setBaseInt(root.get(baseInt).asInt());
            names.remove(baseInt);
        }

        return baseClass;
    }

    private List<String> getNames(ObjectNode root) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        root.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(names::add);

        return names;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseJson = "{"
                + "\"baseInt\": 1,\n"
                + "\t\"customObject\" : {\n"
                + "\t\t\"key\": \"value\"\n"
                + "\t},\n"
                + "\t\"customString\" : \"STRING\""
                + "}";

        String extendedJson = "{"
                + "\t\"baseInt\": 1,\n"
                + "\t\"customObject\" : {\n"
                + "\t\t\"key\": \"value\"\n"
                + "\t},\n"
                + "\t\"customString\" : \"STRING\",\n"
                + "\t\"extendedString\" : \"STRING\"\n"
                + "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(baseJson, BaseClass.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(extendedJson, BaseClass.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(extendedJson, ExtendedClass.class));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
BaseClass{customFields={"customObject":{"key":"value"},"customString":"STRING"}, baseInt=1}
ExtendedClass{extendedString='STRING'} BaseClass{customFields={"customObject":{"key":"value"},"customString":"STRING"}, baseInt=1}
ExtendedClass{extendedString='STRING'} BaseClass{customFields={"customObject":{"key":"value"},"customString":"STRING"}, baseInt=1}
```

Improvements:

- In `BaseClass` class instead of `ObjectNode` use `Map<String, JsonNode>` or even `Map<String, Object>`. It is not a good idea to tie `POJO` classes with `3-rd party libraries`.
- You do not need to use `@JsonProperty` annotation if you manually handle deserialisation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but doesn't that make the BaseClass not very extendable? Like for all future classes that extend the BaseClass, I will have to go back and edit the deserializer for it accordingly.

Comment: @Man-KitYau, Unfortunately it looks like this. If you do not have a list of types and you are not able to use `@JsonTypeInfo`, `@JsonSubTypes` and [other annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) you need to implement custom type recognising mechanism. In your case you can do that by checking properties which `JSON` payload contains. If you would like to make it easy extendable you need to create `type`  property which will inform `Jackson` which type you expect to deserialise.